# Hot to split string to an array in this situation?

Tags: javascript

I get twenty youtube ids , i want to get the first and second id.

the 20 data like this:

```
/watch?v=2ZBaOvX6ktU,/watch?v=7bj15kbLOZU,/watch?v=UYh1yxSi2UA,/watch?v=72qeHHapFF8,/watch?v=vkmvqhArZ8M,/watch?v=adadLSFLAd4,/watch?v=MkOYvjq50c8,/watch?v=h8gcqI0s9hM,/watch?v=g_olO2htTi0,/watch?v=vaWSeYdGqjM,/watch?v=ZDak5qhlLoU,/watch?v=68Uo_yn_ssc,/watch?v=sIaoXv69IJA,/watch?v=asiDjf546W8,/watch?v=bfxikjXaki4,/watch?v=wRvG6ZjFD28,/watch?v=0Kj3XhLqAQM,/watch?v=nN42e8AM4R4,/watch?v=ST0EZqRdQKI
```

But when i try to split the string put it into an array, it shows `TypeError: undefined is not a constructo`

I don't know why any suggestion would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
var youtubeId = [];

youtubeId[idCount] = this.evaluate(getYoutubeId);

console.log(youtubeId[idCount]);// 20 data

var sourceId = youtubeId[idCount];

var id = [];

id = sourceId.split(",");// this code show error

console.log('\n' + id + '\n');
```

Comment: this.evaluate(getYoutubeId) returns a string ?

Comment: @marvel308 Looks like it returns an array

Comment: id = sourceId.split(","); won't work if it is an array

Comment: Thanks for remind , i think its a string at first...

Comment: split worked form me. ["/watch?v=2ZBaOvX6ktU", "/watch?v=7bj15kbLOZU", "/watch?v=UYh1yxSi2UA", "/watch?v=72qeHHapFF8", "/watch?v=vkmvqhArZ8M", "/watch?v=adadLSFLAd4", "/watch?v=MkOYvjq50c8", "/watch?v=h8gcqI0s9hM", "/watch?v=g_olO2htTi0", "/watch?v=vaWSeYdGqjM", "/watch?v=ZDak5qhlLoU", "/watch?v=68Uo_yn_ssc", "/watch?v=sIaoXv69IJA", "/watch?v=asiDjf546W8", "/watch?v=bfxikjXaki4", "/watch?v=wRvG6ZjFD28", "/watch?v=0Kj3XhLqAQM", "/watch?v=nN42e8AM4R4", "/watch?v=ST0EZqRdQKI"]

Comment: mybad. u r doing split on sourceID

Comment: It's totally fine , thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If 20 youtube id is in single line and you want to print 2 youtube id then below code should work for you.

Here, I first splitted your whole string by comma so i get 19 string then i again splitted by equality sign(=) so i get two section out of which second one is your id.

This will print ID like 2ZBaOvX6ktU and then in next line it will print 7bj15kbLOZU.

```
var string = "/watch?v=2ZBaOvX6ktU,/watch?v=7bj15kbLOZU,/watch?v=UYh1yxSi2UA,/watch?v=72qeHHapFF8,/watch?v=vkmvqhArZ8M,/watch?v=adadLSFLAd4,/watch?v=MkOYvjq50c8,/watch?v=h8gcqI0s9hM,/watch?v=g_olO2htTi0,/watch?v=vaWSeYdGqjM,/watch?v=ZDak5qhlLoU,/watch?v=68Uo_yn_ssc,/watch?v=sIaoXv69IJA,/watch?v=asiDjf546W8,/watch?v=bfxikjXaki4,/watch?v=wRvG6ZjFD28,/watch?v=0Kj3XhLqAQM,/watch?v=nN42e8AM4R4,/watch?v=ST0EZqRdQKI";
var arr = string.split(/[\s,]+/);
    console.log(arr[0].split("=")[1]);
    console.log(arr[1].split("=")[1]);
```

If you want to print "/watch?v=2ZBaOvX6ktU" then you can write console.log(arr[i]);

Comment: Thank you so much , it works now !   I'm still try to understand your code that regular express is hard for me.  Also , i find what is wrong with my error , i should change the code like this `var sourceId = "'" +youtubeId[idCount] + "'";` then will fix the error.

Comment: Here, I first splitted your whole string by comma so i get 19 string then i again splitted by equality sign(=) so i get two section out of which second one is your id.

Comment: I get it now !  Thank you TechnoCrat.

Answer (score 0):

If 20 youtube ids are in a single string you can get the first two ids as follows.

```
var str = //your 20 ids string here
var res = str.split(",");
alert("first",res[0]);
alert("second",res[1]);
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your help , i get the answer from TechnoCrat.